# Excel Macro does not display properly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that is supposed to copy the format of a row and insert a new row with the same format.

Here is the macro code:

```
Sub Insertion_ligne_verrouillée()
'
' Insertion_ligne_verrouillée Macro
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Copy
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    On Error Resume Next
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
     'Application.CutCopyMode=False
End Sub
```

Now i am not the one that wrote the macro and honestly my VBA is quite rusty (also not that good in VBA either). The problem i am having is the user is using the macro by selecting a row and using ctrl+L.

It does copy and insert a row with the right format, however some rows afterward seem empty (all blank and no row number) so you have to select the row > right click > display, for it to display properly

Not sure what to look for

Answer (score 0):

The following code makes a new row below the row you want to copy then copies the format of the row and paste into the new row.

```
Sub Insertion_ligne_verrouillée()
  'Make a new row below active cell
  ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, 
  CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromRightOrAbove
  'Copy the active row
  ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
  'paste format into new row
  ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```